# Get Month, Year from MYSQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I want to get Year,Month values to php which are already inserted in mysql database. I've try this SQL code. but it is not work

```
        $sql = "SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP 'paid_time') FROM tbl_pkg_payment_details WHERE client_email='info@n.com'";
```

paid_time is my Table's timestamp column name. What is the exact code for it?

Comment: Who is the foolish who gives negative feedback for this important question??

Comment: What is the column name of the timestamp, `paid_time`? Do you want the month name (January, February, ...) or month number (1, 2, ...)?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. Answers to these types of questions generally reside there. [Try this page, for instance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) from MySQL.

If you want the month name use:

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTHNAME(paid_time) as month, YEAR(paid_time) as year FROM tbl_pkg_payment_details WHERE client_email='info@n.com'";
```

If you want the month number use:

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(paid_time) as month, YEAR(paid_time) as year FROM tbl_pkg_payment_details WHERE client_email='info@n.com'";
```

Comment: Where's the year.... ?

Comment: Added it in ... it was in the question so I should have included it but it wasn't in the query provided.